how to pass variables that contain spaces into docker run?
Given I have the following variable in my Github repository
MYVAR: My Var

Then I have this part that is executed in Github Actions:
if then... // conditionally setting some variables

MYVAR = ${{vars.MYVAR}}

docker run \
-d \
-e MYVAR=$MYVAR \ // error triggered here
ghcr.io/xxx/xxx/:${{github.sha}}-${{github.ref_name}}

But I get the following error during workflow run:
err: bash: line 3: Test: command not found

An odd thing:
If using github secrets I can simply escape the space character
My\ Var
and then docker won't complain.

Use quotation marks.

@KlausD. this didn't work. The values are empty within my application again.

I echo the values to a file, and they are intact. Passing them to docker run results in an empty string.

Also there must not be any spaces in variable assignments.

got no spaces in my version.

MYVAR = ${{vars.MYVAR}} → two spaces, no quotation marks

as I said, it logs the variables to the file, but they are empty in the docker environment.

Quote your variables, e.g.
MYVAR="${{vars.MYVAR}}"
docker run \
  -d \
  -e "MYVAR=$MYVAR" \
  "ghcr.io/xxx/xxx/:${{github.sha}}-${{github.ref_name}}"

